# How to allocate memory for input string of unknown length?

Tags: c, string

This is the struct:

```
typedef struct _friend {
        char *firstname;
        char *lastname;
        char birthdate[9];
} friend;
```

I'm confused about how to have the user input a string and have it placed in the `friend` structure as `firstname` (or `lastname`).  Also, what if the user enters more than 256 characters when I use `fgets`? This is what I have so far...

```
friend *f = (friend *)malloc(sizeof(friend));  //initialize f pointer to friend
char *str;

fgets(str,256,stdin);
f->firstname = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str)+1));
strcpy(f->firstname,str);
```

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in a C program.

Comment: You did not allocate memory for `str`.

Comment: How would I allocate memory for it, if I do not know how long the string will be that the user enters? @Musa

Comment: Set a reasonable limit, 256 is many times longer than any name I've ever come across. `str = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);`

Answer (score 2):

Well, since `stdin` is a buffered input, you can use `fgetc` to read input character by character until you hit a newline or EOF. Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct friend {
        char    *firstname;
        char    *lastname;
        char     birthdate[9];
};

static char *read_line(FILE *f)
{
    char    *r = NULL;
    char    *p = r;
    char    *e = p;
    int  c;

    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        if (p >= e) {
            size_t   l = e > r ? (size_t)(e - r) : 32u;
            char    *x = realloc(r, l);
            if (!x) {
                free(r);
                r = NULL;
                goto out;
            }
            p = x + (p - r);
            e = x + l;
            r = x;
        }
        if (c != '\n') {
            *p++ = (char)c;
        } else {
            *p++ = '\0';
            goto out;
        }
    }
    if (ferror(f) != 0) {
        free(r);
        r = NULL;
    }
out:
    return r;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct friend f;

    memset(&f, 0, sizeof(struct friend));

    printf("Please enter your first name: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    f.firstname = read_line(stdin);
    if (!f.firstname)
        goto on_error;
    printf("Please enter your last name: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    f.lastname = read_line(stdin);
    if (!f.lastname)
        goto on_error;

    printf("You first name is: %s\n", f.firstname);
    printf("Your last name is: %s\n", f.lastname);

    free(f.firstname);
    free(f.lastname);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

on_error:
    perror("read_line");
    free(f.firstname);
    free(f.lastname);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no one-size-fits-all solution for this problem.  Any particular engineer might use one of several solutions for the same problem based on various criteria:

- Should the solution be dead stupid simple?
- Should it adapt flexibly to a wide range of input lengths?
- Will the code run only in a limited range of environments where adequate memory is known to be available?
- Will anyone else have to understand the solution, like for ongoing maintenance?

For a simple solution in a known, adequate memory environment, I might do this:

```
char  buf [1000];  // for English names, this should be big enough
friend f;  // not a pointer, but a full struct
if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
{
      perror ("error reading from stdin");
      return;
}
f.firstname = strdup (buf);  // allocates the right size of memory and copies

...
// when finished with the structure, deallocate the dynamic strings:
free (f.firstname);
```

Notice how this almost completely avoids manipulating pointers?  (Only `strdup()` is doing it, and it neatly encapsulates the essential operation.) This is a feature of robust, low-troublemaking code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

Have a separate buffer for user input. Then after the user has entered data into this buffer you parse it and determine if it's sane (e.g. if it's not an empty string, and if it doesn't contain any numbers or other strange characters), and strip excess whitespace, etc. If the data is acceptable, determine how long it actually is and allocate the correct amount of memory to copy it into.

For getting user input into the separate buffer, don't use `fgets()`. Instead use `fgetc()` in a loop, so that you can increase the size of the buffer when necessary. For example, you might start with a small 32-byte buffer, and then double the size of the buffer (with `realloc()`) whenever it becomes full.