# How to read input of unknown length using fgets

Tags: c, string, input, string-length

How am I supposed to read long input using `fgets()`, I don't quite get it.

I wrote this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[10];
    char *input;
    while (fgets(buffer,10,stdin)){
        input = malloc(strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(input,buffer);
    }
    printf("%s [%d]",input, (int)strlen(input));
    free(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at `realloc`. And consider a strategy of doubling the allocation each time, as well as reading directly into the buffer. BTW: The printf-format for `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: If you have it, consider using [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) instead of `fgets`.

Comment: i know about getline, but i have to use fgets

Comment: i saw them but i dont understand from it how fgets works, what happens when input is longer then buffer i specify, does it wait for me to allocate memory and store it there?

Comment: There are definitely other questions that cover exactly this topic:
[How to allocate memory for input string of unknown length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878240/); [Safely reading in strings of unknown length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507995/); and probably others.

Comment: If the buffer isn't big enough to fit the whole line, `fgets()` returns the buffer filled as much as it can, and null-terminated, and leaves you to decide what to do with the rest of the line which is waiting to be read by the next input operation.

Comment: Your code has a classic off-by-one error in the `malloc()`.  Using `strlen(str)` is almost always wrong; it should almost always be `strlen(str)+1`.  Your loop leaks memory horribly, too; you overwrite the previous pointer stored in `input` on each iteration.

Comment: is there any function that appends string? because i am also rewriting input by that one part that is left to be read

Comment: There's `strcat()`, but you don't want to use it for this task.  There's also `strncat()`; you even more definitely don't want to use it because its interface is just a booby-trap.  To use `strcat()` safely, you have to know how much space is available in the buffer to be copied into, how long the string already in the buffer is, and how much space is in the string to be appended to the end of it, and if you know those, you can use `memmove()` or `memcpy()`, or even `strcpy()`, to copy the correct amount of data into exactly the correct position.

Comment: Be careful of someone accidentally or maliciously on purpose giving you a binary file.  You may not want to print it in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[10];
    char *input = 0;
    size_t cur_len = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
    {
        size_t buf_len = strlen(buffer);
        char *extra = realloc(input, buf_len + cur_len + 1);
        if (extra == 0)
            break;
        input = extra;
        strcpy(input + cur_len, buffer);
        cur_len += buf_len;
    }
    printf("%s [%d]", input, (int)strlen(input));
    free(input);
    return 0;
}
```

This is about the minimal set of changes that will give you the complete line of input.  This grows the space by up to 9 bytes at a time; that isn't the best way to do it, but there's extra bookkeeping involved doing it the better ways (doubling the space allocated, and keeping a record of how much is allocated vs how much is in use).  Note that `cur_len` record the length of the string in the space pointed to by `input` excluding the terminal null.  Also note that the use of `extra` avoids a memory leak on failure to allocate.

The `strcpy()` operation could be legitimately replaced by `memmove(input + cur_len, buffer, buf_len + 1)` (and in this context, you could use `memcpy()` instead of `memmove()`, but it doesn't always work while `memmove()` does always work, so it is more reliable to use `memmove()`).

---

With length-doubling — the `cur_max` variable records how much space is allocated, and `cur_len` records how much space is in use.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[10];
    char *input = 0;
    size_t cur_len = 0;
    size_t cur_max = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
    {
        size_t buf_len = strlen(buffer);
        if (cur_len + buf_len + 1 > cur_max)
        {
            size_t new_len = cur_max * 2 + 1;
            if (buf_len + 1 > new_len)
                new_len = buf_len + 1;
            char *extra = realloc(input, new_len);
            if (extra == 0)
                break;
            input = extra;
            cur_max = new_len;
        }
        strcpy(input + cur_len, buffer);
        cur_len += buf_len;
    }
    printf("%s [%d]", input, (int)strlen(input));
    free(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, so if i wanted to read lines that are generally very long, i have to use realloc resizing by 2 times more than its previous size?

Comment: No; the simplest thing is to use `char buffer[4096];` and get on with life.  Only JSON comes in lines longer than that, and then you get to read the whole file in one line.  (I exaggerate, but not by as much as all that.)  Failing that, the idea is that you allocate 10 bytes the first time, then reallocate 20, then reallocate 40 (but read 2 units of 10 into the extra space), then 80, then 160, then 320...  If you're not going to free the space before the function exits and there's more than, say, 64 bytes unused, you might use `realloc()` to shrink the allocation to its required size.

Comment: Unless you're on a tiny, tiny machine, a 4 KiB buffer isn't going to cause you grief.  If you're on such a tiny machine, you probably aren't using `malloc()` at all - or reading such long lines.

Comment: thanks for the answer, what does if (extra == 0)
            break; this do in your modification, is 0 representiing 'NULL'?

Comment: NULL is another name for 0 - more or less.  There are complications, but both are (or can be) null pointer constants.  You can use 0 in places that you should not use NULL; there's nowhere you can use NULL that you can't use 0.  In C, some systems define NULL as `((void *)0)` or thereabouts; that doesn't fly in C++ (but the correct value for NULL is a problem for the compiler, not the programmer using NULL).  You can use NULL where I wrote 0 in: `char *input = NULL;`, `while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)`, `if (extra == NULL)`.

Comment: could you please show me how to implement this with resizing it each time 2 times?

Answer (score 3):

A better approach is to use an input mechanism that will allocate for you such as `getline` (or even `scanf`). (**Note:** `scanf` does not allocate in all compilers. It does in `gcc/Linux`, but does not with `Windows/Codeblocks/gcc`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *input;
    scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &input);
    printf("\n %s [%d]\n\n",input, (int)strlen(input));
    free(input);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/scanfinput
This is my longer string.

 This is my longer string. [25]
```

---

**getline example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *input = NULL;     /* input buffer, NULL forces getline to allocate */
    size_t n = 0;           /* maximum characters to read (0 - no limit      */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;       /* number of characters actually read            */

    if ((nchr = getline (&input, &n, stdin)) != -1)
        input[--nchr] = 0;  /* strip newline */

    printf ("\n %s [%zd]\n\n", input, nchr);
    free(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this gives me warning, unknown format %m, im working with c90

Comment: If you are working in Windows, `scanf` will not allocate if using `codeblocks`, etc.., Use `getline`. I'll update for Linux only. I was working with `gcc/C89` with gnu extensions.

Comment: Get rid of codeblocks `:)` I've had others report that `scanf` will not allocate if using `codeblocks`. It must be a limitation.

Comment: Code::Blocks has nothing to do with the compile.  Its just the IDE

Comment: What is the bottom line there? I had another report that using a `gcc` setup on windows with codeblocks, `scanf` could not allocate. I have neither and no way to test.

Comment: The ability to allocate or not is an implementation issue with whatever compiler OP is using.  I have used the MinGW implementation for several projects without a hitch, but do not have it now to test the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So it is just a roll of the dice on implementations other than Gnu Linux. It would be readily apparent from the `man page` you would think. Either you have the `m` designation for causing `scanf` to allocate or you don't. I'm curious if there is actually an absence in the `man pages` on the implementations where it fails. (maybe I should say I would be 'surprised' to see an absence...)