# fgets() is working awkwardly

Tags: c, fgets

So for a long time I have used scanf(), but it always bothered me when the input is longer then the string so it messes up the code (changes other ints and the like).

So I was told that I should instead use fgets(), because it can limit the amount of letters and symbols it reads.

But fgets() always also includes the newline (\n), so I was advised to use the command `input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = '\0';`, which should remove the \n from the string.

And of course there was one more problem. When the input was longer than the string one of a two things happened:

*1. it leaves the input on screen and only moves my cursor one line lower, which effectively softlocks my program.* (not true, fixed it by making the program loop correctly)

2. it skips the next fgets() (one or more).

I read somwhere it might be because fgets() reads the rest of the input when it is next called, but I tried emptying the string every time before I wrote to it again, but it didn't help a slight bit.

Anyone knows how to fix this problem? It has been bothering me for some time, as I have never achived a perfect input to string program (with failsafes as people make mistakes)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char input[3];

int main(){
    begin:
    fgets(input, 3, stdin);
    input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = '\0';
    if(strcmp(input, "1")==0){
        printf("input = 1\n");
    }
    else if(strcmp(input, "2")==0){
        printf("input = 2\n");
    }
    goto begin;
}
```

Sadly I could not recreate the 1st problem, but the second works by typing xx1 or xx2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `while(1)` for an infinite loop, not `goto`

Comment: What do you mean "I tried emptying the string every time before I wrote to it again"? That doesn't change what `fgets()` does. The first call will read `xx` and put it into the string, the second call will read `1\n`. Emptying the string doesn't change that.

Comment: Add an `else` clause after the `else if` clause. `else { printf("input = %s\n", input); }`. That might help you understand what's happening.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out when it didn't work. (Barmar)

Comment: *"But fgets() always also includes the newline"* - read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) of that again, because that isn't guaranteed.At most `count-1` characters are read, stopping (and including) the newline if that is encountered prior to reaching that limit. Your code with an input of `"1234\n"` would put `"12"` in your buffer and terminate the string, leaving `"34\n"` in the input stream.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read input of unknown length using fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326839/how-to-read-input-of-unknown-length-using-fgets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check whether `fgets()` read an entire line, by testing whether the last character is newline. If so, replace the newline with a null byte; if not, keep reading characters until you get a newline.

```
char *c = fgets(input, 3, stdin);
if (c == NULL) { // EOF reached
    break;
}
if (input[strlen(input)-1] == '\n') {
    input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
} else {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Note for the OP (and anyone else that cares): take great care in using `strlen(s)-1` as an index to `s`. If the string is empty the results will *not* be what you want. `fgets` should be checked

Comment: Thanks, the code works perfectly now. The only thing that I would want to point out is that when I wrote that longer input than string would result in a softlock, I didn't realize that the "softlock" was bad on my side for not looping the section of program correctly.

Comment: If the input is redirected from a file, the last line in a file might not have a newline. I would say the answer should involve `malloc` and `realloc`

Comment: Also take care not to try reading for another line if `eof(stdin)` is true.  A missing newline on the very last line of the file will cause problems otherwise.

Comment: @MikeHousky I've added an EOF check.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think the EOF/error check I just added should be sufficient. `fgets()` can't return an empty string when it's successful.

Comment: Not sure why `malloc()/realloc()` is necessary, unless you're trying to duplicate the functionality of `getline()`, which can return any size line.

Comment: The last line not ending with newline is already handled. The `if` will fail, so it doesn't replace newline with `\0`. Then it goes into the loop that reads until newline or EOF, which should stop immediately. Then the next `fgets()` will return `NULL`.

Comment: The question was not phrased so well, but its first sentence says "when the input is longer than the string", which is why I made the earlier comment about memory allocation, and posted the "possible duplicate" comment above, but refrained from closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code::

1. eliminates the `goto`
2. makes use of the returned value from `fgets()`
3. does not include header files those contents are not used
4. allows the fact that "\n" handles any other 'end of line' sequence.
5. eliminates the 'magic' numbers

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_LEN 3

char input[ BUF_LEN ];

int main( void )
{
    while(  fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) )
    {
        input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';

        if(strcmp(input, "1")==0){
            printf("input = 1\n");
        }

        else if(strcmp(input, "2")==0){
            printf("input = 2\n");
        }
    }
}
```

here is a typical run of the code (remember that the looping continues even when nothing is printed:

```
1
input = 1
2
input = 2
3
4
5
6
1
input = 1
kj;lkj;lkj
1jklkl;j
1
input = 1
x1
xx1
input = 1
```