# String array as long as input

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

In C, I want to take an input from the user but I don't know how long is it. I think I should use `malloc()` to set the length of the text array:

```
char *text = NULL;
text = malloc(sizeof(input))
```

But, how can I do it at the same time that I'm storing the input to the array with `fgets()`?

```
fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin)
```

Comment: First allocate an initial buffer for the string, with some fixed size.  Then call `fgets`, limiting the length to the size of the buffer.  If it reads less, then you can call `realloc` to reduce the size and you're done.  But if there might be more, then call `realloc` to double the size of the buffer, continue reading, and repeat as needed.

Comment: You can also allocate multiple buffers and chain them together as a linked list.

Comment: If I got you right you should try to do like in this link:
[How to read input of unknown length using fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326839/how-to-read-input-of-unknown-length-using-fgets)

Comment: You're pretty much most definite never going to use `char* text = malloc(sizeof(input))`. That is, unless `input` happens to be a statically allocated `char` array (in which case, since you know the size of the static array, you would most likely not need to allocate another one dynamically).

Comment: `sizeof text` is the size of the pointer - irrelevant to reading user input.

Comment: Actually `fgets` will automatically do what you need, it keeps reading from the input until newline, end of file or reached the num-1 specified by its signature and returns a pointer of an array of char with the length of text read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string stored as a result of calling `fgets` will contain a newline if it can fit in the buffer.  If the read string ends in a newline you know you have a full line.  If not, you know you need to read more.

So start by using `malloc` to allocate a buffer of a certain size.  Then use `fgets` to populate the buffer.  If there's no newline in the buffer, use `realloc` to expand it and use `fgets` again, starting at the offset you left off at.

Alternately, if you're on a POSIX system like Linux you can just use `getline` which does all of this for you.