# How can I convert my strings to lowercase?

Tags: c

The code is intended to check whether two words are anagrams or not. I'd like it to be case sensitive, however using `strlwr` is creating errors. How can I alter it so that it works for both lower and uppercase? Currently it only works for one or the other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort(char str[]);

int main(void){ 
    char FirstWord[10];
    char SecondWord[10];

    printf("Enter the first word \n");
    scanf("%s", FirstWord);
    printf("Enter the second word \n");
    scanf("%s", SecondWord);


    sort(FirstWord);
    sort(SecondWord);

    if(strcmp(FirstWord, SecondWord)==0)
       printf("First word and second word are the same \n");
    else
       printf("Words are different \n");
}

void sort(char str[]){
    int i,j,swapper, ArrayLength = strlen(str);

    for(i=0; i<ArrayLength; i++)
        for(j=0; j<ArrayLength; j++)
            if (str[i] < str[j]){
                swapper=str[i];
                str[i]=str[j];
                str[j]=swapper;
            }
}
```

Comment: Don't say "creating errors", instead please show the *exact* error text you received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `strlwr` is, but you can use either [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) or [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) from the standard library to convert both strings to lowercase or uppercase (respectively), then do the comparison.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    FirstWord[i] = tolower(FirstWord[i]);
}
```

On another note, you should perfer `fgets` over `scanf` when reading input of a unknown length, to avoid reading more than your buffer will allow. See [How to read input of unknown length using fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326839/how-to-read-input-of-unknown-length-using-fgets/27327168#27327168)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `strcasecmp` function, which does a case-insensitive comparison.  This is available on POSIX compatible systems (i.e. Linux, UNIX, OSX).  For Windows, use `stricmp`.

EDIT:

Because you're sorting the characters before doing the comparison, a simple case insensitive comparison isn't enough.

You need to first convert each string to lowercase using `strlwr`, then call `sort` on each string.  Then you can compare with `strcmp`.

Comment: @smac89 It's not, but gave an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Using only standard C and assuming this is an exercise, you could create a function to lowercase any string.
If you look at an ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/), every character from A to Z has a corresponding ASCII code. Every lowercase character has a different ASCII code.

Very roughly, your function can look at a character in a string, check if its ASCII code is within A-Z, and if it is, add 32 (which is the distance between uppercase and lowercase characters).

So something like this:

```
void lowercase(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0 ; str[i] ; i++) {
        if ( str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90) {
            str[i] = str[i] + 32;
        }
    }
}
```

(Not claiming this is perfect, just showing the idea)

Note that char arrays (strings) are passed by reference (not value) to the function, so changing str[i] within the function changes the original character. Now you can just call this function on both your inputs before doing the comparison.

Comment: Be careful.  Your function fails if passed a string literal as string literals are read-only and trying to modify them invokes undefined behavior.